# HOW to get FILE handle in LLVM on windows

Tags: file, llvm

I'm trying to implement a script interpreter on windows using LLVM C++ API.there's a perl-like statement like

```
myInput=<stdin>;
```

i don't want to use similar function in C and link them with it.So how to bind  or something like that to STDIN or a more generic FILE handle with LLVM APIs?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use external functions from the LLVM Interpreter, see `lib/ExecutionEngine/Interpreter/ExternalFunctions.cpp`. In this case, you can use the C library's `fgets` to read `stdin`, or define a more convenient wrapper around it which your script can invoke directly. Note that the LLVM interpreter or JIT can find such functions within the LLVM process itself since it always links with the C runtime, so you don't need to open additional DLLs.